# JSON in Android Database

Tags: android, database, json

i am very new to Android development and Json. I would like to implement following functionality....

I have designed a UI form where the user will enter some information about his Phone, name, his photo, address etc.  Now what i want to do is: (please correct if i am moving in the wrong direction) i want to take the information entered in the form and to store the whole information as a JSON string in the Database.
So for every user who fills the form, there will be a unique json string about his information in the database.
How should i go about doing this? 
should i first retrieve the whole data in an array then convert it to jsONObject or JSON string or JSONArray? 
i am pretty confused about how these things work and are inter-related with each-other?

help!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this Idea fails the main purpose to keep database tables and their Fields..Json is mostly used when data is coming from server or Url. Parsing Json you could get data you want and store it to your local database..

Nevertheless here is some easy way to use json :[JSON PARSING](http://droidketchup.blogspot.in/2012/03/simple-json-parser-in-android.html)

Comment: actually i am trying to send the data over NFC..... so the form data that i will be storing in the database (in the form of JSON string) are actually different cards (Business, personal...etc ) created by the user itself. So i thought that fetching data and passing it over NFC in the form of JSON string will be efficient